# How to reset a particular form field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to reset a particular form field using jQuery.

I'm using the folowing function:

```
function resetForm(id) {
    $('#'+id).each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
}
```

but it is resetting all the fields. Is there any way to reset specific fields using jQuery or JavaScript? I want to reset only a particular field.

Comment: [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) affects the whole form, by design. How are the 'default' values assigned, through the `value` attribute?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
function resetForm(id) {
    $('#' + id).val(function() {
        return this.defaultValue;
    });
}
```

example without using id:

http://jsfiddle.net/vYWdm/

Comment: Note that this approach only applies to text fields. Just tried to apply this to a select field, and it doesn't work. For use cases like mine you can use the data based approach suggested by David Thomas below.

Comment: For select fields, you should be able to use the `defaultSelected` attribute of the option elements.  Just be careful, because if you ever set the `selected` attribute using `setAttribute`, IE8 will reparse, and `defaultSelected` will also be updated.

Comment: For select inputs I used this code; `$tr.find('select option').each(function (index, element) {
      $(element).prop('selected', this.defaultSelected)
    })`

Answer (score 10):

The `reset()` method affects the whole form, by design, to reset only particular `input` elements, assuming that there's a Reset previous input`element after each`input`:

```
$('button.reset').click(
    function(){
        var input = $(this).prev('input:first');
        input.val(''); // assuming you want it reset to an empty state;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bcAzG/1/)

To reset the `input` to its original state, then first I'd recommend storing the original value in a `data-*` attribute for recollection:

```
$('input').each(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('data-originalValue',$(this).val());
    });

$('button.reset').click(
    function(){
        var input = $(this).prev('input:first');
        input.val(input.attr('data-originalValue'));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bcAzG/)

Given HTML similar to the following (in which the `input` elements are grouped together):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input value="something" />
        <button class="reset">Reset the input</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="two"  />
        <input type="checkbox" name="two" checked />
        <input type="checkbox" name="two"  />
        <button class="reset">Reset the input</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="three" checked />
        <input type="radio" name="three" />
        <button class="reset">Reset the input</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The following jQuery will reset the `input` elements back to their page-load state:

```
$('button.reset').click(
    function () {
        $(this).prevAll('input').val(function(){
            switch (this.type){
                case 'text':
                    return this.defaultValue;
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    this.checked = this.defaultChecked;
            }
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bcAzG/249/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset)
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: +1 for setting up the original values in a data-attribute based on the form values on startup..

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to consider three cases: free-input-based fields, check-based fields and select-based fields.

```
$(set_of_fields).each(function() {
  // Don't bother checking the field type, just check if property exists
  // and set it
  if (typeof(this.defaultChecked) !== "undefined")
    this.checked = this.defaultChecked;
  if (typeof(this.defaultValue) !== "undefined")
    this.value = this.defaultValue;

  // Try to find an option with selected attribute (not property!)
  var defaultOption = $(this).find('option[selected]');
  // and fallback to the first option
  if (defaultOption.length === 0)
    defaultOption = $(this).find('option:first');
  // if no option was found, then it was not a select
  if (defaultOption.length > 0)
    this.value = defaultOption.attr('value');
});
```

*Edit: I just noticed this won't work with `<select multiple>` fields.*

Answer (score -4):

You could do (if you plan to use the [reset()](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-reset-method.shtml) javascript method):

```
function resetForm(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).reset();
}
```

There is no need for jQuery as the method "reset" is a standard javascript method

Comment: Actually I just reread the question--the OP wants to reset only certain elements, not the whole form.