# Reset button to default value for input box

Tags: jquery

I have an inputbox where visitors can change the value

```
<input id="custom_coverage" type="text" value="320" name="custom_coverage">
```

When they change the value, it makes a calculation on the by another jQuery-script.

How can i add a button or a link next to the input box, so visitors can put it back to the default value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset a particular form field using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667926/how-to-reset-a-particular-form-field-using-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store the original value in a `data` attribute, e.g. `<input id="custom_coverage" type="text" value="320" data-original-value="320" name="custom_coverage">`

And add a button that switches the values again:

```
<a href="#" class="restore">Restore</a>

<script>

  $(document).on("click", ".restore", function(){
    var custom_coverage = $("input#custom_coverage");
    custom_coverage.val(custom_coverage.data("original-value"));

  });

</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/deDdy/

Comment: +1, only solution that works with dynamically changed value attribute!

Comment: thx, how can i restore multiple input boxes to the default value?

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/deDdy/1/ - Just make sure the elements don't share the same `id` and `name`

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it this way:

```
<input type="reset" value="Restore" />
```

But it will reset all the form, not only one input.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is inside of a form you can use a "reset" type input button.

```
<form action="mySubmit">
<input id="custom_coverage" type="text" value="320" name="custom_coverage">
<input type="reset" value="BUTTON NAME HERE">
</form>
```

Alternatively if you know what the original value is you can do something like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#custom_coverage').val('ORIGINAL VALUE');" value="Reset"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to reset the value to whatever you want.

```
defaultValue = 320;
resetValue = function() {
   $('#custom_coverage').val(defaultValue)
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HdZ3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var default_value = $('#custom_coverage').val();
    $('#reset_value').click(function(){
        $(this).val(default_value);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
<input id="custom_coverage" type="text" value="320" name="custom_coverage" id="custom_coverage">
<a href="#" id="reset_value">Reset input</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store that value on the `data` attribute of the button and assign it back to the input on the click of the button.

```
var $input = $('#custom_coverage'),
    $reset = $('#reset')
$('#reset').data('default', $input.val() );

$reset.on('click', function() {
   $input.val($(this).data('default')); 
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZCqDp/)**