# Reset Input and Textarea fields without form.reset

Tags: javascript, html, button, reset

For a few reasons, I can't have a `<form>` tag on the page, but I do have `<form>` elements like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<button>`. I have a reset button and I need to reset everything inside the input and textareas when I click the button. There's also quite a few input boxes.

Additionally, there is a php script that fills in `<span>` tags with requested information that I would also like to make blank again when pressing the button.

Some example code below

HTML

```
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset Fields</button>

<input id="myID" type="text">

<input id="myID2" type="text">

<span id="mySpan">Some text here</span>
<span id="mySpan2">Some text here</span>
```

Comment: It's really helpful in these situations to make a bin.  It's also helpful to not have typos in your code.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @D.Walsh haha my bad. I edited it. I rushed out the example code.

Comment: @BJohnson I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8668089/620039) answer also solves this problem if you wanted some fields to reset. Although you have to handle span cases separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is what you want:

```
function resetFields(){
    var inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    inputArray.forEach(function (input){
        input.value = "";
    });

    var textAreaArray = document.querySelectorAll('textArea');
    textAreaArray.forEach(function (textArea){
        textArea.innerHTML = "";
    });

    var spanArray = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    spanArray.forEach(function (span){
        span.innerHTML = "";
    });

}
```

Comment: That would be great. Unfortunately right now when I hit the reset button it either deletes/hides all the form elements. Any idea why?

Comment: i have to see your form tag to tell you why, i have tried it in jsFiddle and it works fine.

Comment: No idea why, but the second time it worked and it works great now. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @BJohnson This solution is the more exact answer for the question, but terrible coding.  Every span, input, or text area on your page will be wiped.  As the page moves through edits over the years, this is a huge source for bugs.

Comment: @D.Walsh he asks for blank ALL these elements.

Comment: @tfidelis I'll type it again for you.  "This solution is the more exact answer for the question, but terrible coding."

Comment: @tfidelis Did exactly what I need. All the page is for is to output raw response of JSON and XML code, who sent the request, and some other stuff contained in the `<span>`'s. It's more likely that the page will get abandoned than become something where we'd need to change code for.

Comment: @D.Walsh explain why it is "terrible coding", please.

Comment: @tfidelis I'll type it again for you.  "Every span, input, or text area on your page will be wiped. As the page moves through edits over the years, this is a huge source for bugs."

Comment: It also can be written in 5 lines.  var x = document.querySelectorAll("textarea, input, span");
  x.forEach(el => {
    el.value='';
    el.innerHTML='';
  })

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/gamubageke/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<script>
function resetFields() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".resettable");
  x.forEach(el => {
    el.value='';
    el.innerHTML='';
  })
}

</script>

<body>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset Fields</button>

<input id="myID" type="text" class="resettable">

<input id="myID2" type="text" class="resettable">

<span id="mySpan" class="resettable">Some text here</span>
<span id="mySpan2" class="resettable">Some text here</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery, you can do something along the lines of

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").val('');
$("#mySpan,#mySpan2").text('');
```