# Reset after ajax call in web2py

Tags: javascript

How to reset the section of form after an ajax call ?

My code:

```
<div id="new2"> <label>Information : </label> <br>
 Target: <br> <input type = "text" name="target"  id="x"> <br>
 Aspects: <br> <input type = "text" name="aspect" id="y" > <br>
 <label>Overall Sentiment :</label>
 <select name ="overall_senti" id="def" >
     <option value="">None</option>
     <option value="Neutral">Neutral</option>
     <option value="Positive">Positive</option>
     <option value="Negative">Negative</option>
 </select> <br>
 <input type="button"  onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default','create_new')}}',['target','aspect','overall_senti'],':eval')" ; document.getElementById('x').reset() value="submit1">
</div>
```

Comment: `reset()` never works on just section but the whole form. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8668150

Comment: Thank you . Now I get it , I did it by document.getElementById('id').value=''